# Spring MVC multiple rows form submit submits new ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Ok its another one of spring's null ModelAttribute but I've tried everything I found but it doesn't work.

I've adding this tutorials functionality to my web app [spring-mvc](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/) everythings workds greate except for when I have to get the data back from the form to my bean.

I use two post methods

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String openEdit(@RequestParam("notfound") String[] notFound,
                           Model model){
        EditForm editForm = editModel.createEditForm(notFound);
        model.addAttribute("editForm",editForm);
        return "Edit/EditOwners";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/saveOwners")
    public String saveOwners(@ModelAttribute("editForm") EditForm editForm){
        editModel.addOwners(editForm);
        return "index";
    }
```

the first one works fine and i can see the data in my Jsp, the second one gets a new ModelAttribute.

This is my form

```
<form:form method="POST" action="saveOwners" modelAttribute="editForm" >
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
                <caption>
                    <h4>Edit The Owners</h4>
                </caption>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${editForm.owners}" var="item" varStatus="status">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${item.name}</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="${owners[status.index].outId}" value="${item.outId}" /> </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="${owners[status.index].type}" value="${item.type}" /> </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </form:form>
```

what seems to be wrong here ? PS i tried my inputs with and without a type attribute and still it gets null, and as I said i can see my data but i can't submit them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding the following annotation to the top of your controller class ?

```
@SessionAttributes({ "editForm" })
public class YourController {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I tired to go just as the example said, I did not want to try session attrs, frankly I never used them so I don't know much about them.

Comment: By adding the session attribute annotation for "editForm" you are basically making this model attribute live through the session, which I believe should fix the problem